# nullPointerException on SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); insert method of ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I got a nullPointerException on the line, listView.setAdapter(adapter); in the main activity class,  cannot figure out what is causing it,  any ideas?

onCreate method of mainActivity class

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
private LoaderManager loaderManager;
private CursorLoader cursorLoader;
private ListView listView;
private int primaryKey;
private String primaryKeyString;
private String testTitle;
private String testText;
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    primaryKey = 0;
    testTitle = "test title";
    testText = "test text";

    primaryKeyString = String.valueOf(primaryKey);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, null,
            new String[]{primaryKeyString, testTitle, testText}, new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3},
            Adapter.NO_SELECTION);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // load database with test values
    loadDatabase();

}

// load database with test data
public void loadDatabase(){
    Uri mNewUri;

    ContentValues mNewValues = new ContentValues();
    mNewValues.put(ProviderExample.NoteItems.TITLE, "test title");
    mNewValues.put(ProviderExample.NoteItems.TEXT, "test text value");

    mNewUri = getContentResolver().insert(ProviderExample.NoteItems.CONTENT_URI, mNewValues);

}
```

the content provider class

```
 public class ProviderExample extends ContentProvider {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notes";
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.contentproviderexample.providerexample";
public static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher;
private static final int NOTES = 1;
private static final int NOTES_ID = 2;
private static HashMap<String, String> notesProjectionMap;

 static {
        sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_NAME, NOTES);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_NAME + "/#", NOTES_ID);
    }

 public static interface NoteItems extends BaseColumns {

        // notes in the CONTENT_URI is often plural where the actual table name is often singular version of this word
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/notes");
        public static final String _ID = "_id";
        public static final String TITLE = "title";
        public static final String TEXT = "text";
        public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/vnd.example.providerexample";
        // static final String SINGLE_RECORD = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.providerexample";
        public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/vnd.example.providerexample";
        // static final String MULTIPLE_RECORDS = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.providerexample"; 
        public static final String[] PROJECTION_ALL = {_ID, TITLE, TEXT};
        public static final String SORT_ORDER_DEFAULT = TITLE + " ASC";

 } // end LentItems interface

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

     DatabaseHelper(Context context){
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + NoteItems._ID + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  
             NoteItems.TITLE + " TEXT, " + NoteItems.TEXT + " TEXT);");

     }

     @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int previousVersion, int newVersion) {
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
     onCreate(db);
     }

 }

private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

 @Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
    if(sUriMatcher.match(uri)!=NOTES){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI" + uri);
    }
    ContentValues values;
    if(initialValues!=null){
        values = new ContentValues(initialValues);
    }else{
        values = new ContentValues();
    }
  SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // <--- nullPointerException here
    long rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

if(rowId > 0){
    Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(NoteItems.CONTENT_URI, rowId);
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(noteUri, null);
    return noteUri;
}
throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
 }
```

EDIT:  now nullPointerException has changed to SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); of insert method

stakctrace:

```
AndroidRuntime(19638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime(19638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contentproviderexample/com.example.contentproviderexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
AndroidRuntime(19638): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
AndroidRuntime(19638):  at com.example.contentproviderexample.ProviderExample.insert(ProviderExample.java:104)
AndroidRuntime(19638):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:189)
AndroidRuntime(19638):  at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:730)
AndroidRuntime(19638):  at com.example.contentproviderexample.MainActivity.loadDatabase(MainActivity.java:76)
/AndroidRuntime(19638):     at com.example.contentproviderexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
```

Comment: You forgot to setContentView

Comment: yes, that fixed the nullPointerException on listView.setAdapter(adapter) problem, but the NullPointerException moved to the SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); line inside of the insert method.

Comment: Post your loadDatabase() method

Comment: loadDatabase() method posted at the end of the first part of the code, mainActivity code

Comment: I think you have to instantiate ProviderExample otherwise dbHelper is null. You have to have a constructor for ProviderExample that has a Context param

Comment: yes that is what caused the NullPointerExcepion,  i instantiated the ProviderExample like this,  ProviderExample prividerExample = new ProviderExample() in the onCreate method and no more NullPointer,  so that problem is solved,  now got innerset, asynctaskException caused by sqlite no such collumn _id, and now working on that problem since the nullPointer is fugured out

Comment: Ok good if you need help on the new NPE post a question with relevant code

Comment: thank you, I am looking at some examples I found on google for "no such column _id"  if I don't figure out this, I will post another question later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without a stacktrace, but it seems that the null pointer isn't the adapter, but the listview. It looks like you haven't called setContentView(), so your findViewById() method is probably returning null, and then you're trying to set an adapter to that null object.

Comment: i updated the question,  yes there was no call to setContentview and I updated that the problem is now inside of the insert method of the content provider, I will add some of the stack trace.

Comment: Well, you didn't so much 'update' the question as ask a new one. Now you have a new null pointer exception in a different part of your code.

I find the easiest way to debug the NPE is to go to your stack trace, and double click on the 'com.example.contentproviderexample.MainActivity.loadDatabase' line.  Click on the first line of stack-trace that will actually take you to a line of code. Then you can see which line is causing the NPE.. Now try and figure out why an object on that line might be null (you probably haven't instantiated it yet)

Comment: yes, you are correct on the fact that it was not instantiated yet